# -Identity parameter in "Enable-SPFeature"

Tags: 2013, powershell, feature, parameter

I just want to confirm `-identity` parameter in `Enable-SPFeature -Identity $parameter -Url $spSiteCollection.Url` Powershell command. In `$parameter` parameter, should we need to provide the ID of feature or Name of feature or Both will work, Just want to clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either will work - the feature ID or the feature name.

From Technet documentation here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607803.aspx

> *Specifies the name of the Feature or GUID to uninstall. The type must be the name of the Feature folder located in the 14\Template\Features
>   folder or GUID, in the form 21d186e1-7036-4092-a825-0eb6709e9281.*

Answer (score 0):

The Enable-SPFeature cmdlet enables an installed feature at the given scope. If the feature is a farm feature, no URL is needed. Otherwise, provide the URL where the feature is to be enabled and it will be enabled at the proper scope based on the Feature definition.

The Identity is a requied field. It is the name of the feature.
For more [info check](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607803.aspx)